# Meaning of a Clifford Geertz quote about the Western conception of the individual

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What does the following quotation from Clifford Geertz mean:

> The Western conception of the person as a bounded, unique, more or less integrated motivational and cognitive universe; a dynamic center of awareness, emotion, judgment, and action organized into a distinctive whole and set contrastively both against other such wholes and against a social and natural background is, however incorrigible it may seem to us, a rather peculiar idea within the context of the world's cultures.
>
> <sub>Clifford Geertz (1974). "[From the Native's Point of View": On the Nature of Anthropological Understanding](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3822971.pdf)". *Bulletin of the American Academy of Arts and Sciences* 28:1, p. 31.</sub>

I do not understand starting from, "and action organized into.....".

Comment: FWIW: *a dynamic center of awareness, emotion, judgment, and action ...*. "Action" is a noun here (in case you have interpreted it as a verb and got lost). But, indeed, the question has little to do with literature, so it does not belong here.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that a person's actions are a part of what makes them a person, along with their emotion, awareness and judgement. This set of qualities defines the whole person. Each whole person is separate from others, so they can be contrasted against others with their own sets of emotions, awareness, judgements and actions. The person can also be differentiated from their social and natural environment. Even though this idea seems to be obvious and unchangeable (incorrigible) to us, it is not how human cultures throughout history have usually understood the nature of a person.

Answer (score 0):

As a background to this, here is a description of [Clifford Geertz's approach to anthropology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thick_description): this may help our understanding of the paragraph quoted in the question.

> He was against comprehensive theories of human behavior; rather, he advocated methodologies that highlight culture from the perspective of how people looked at and experienced life.

---

> (1) The Western conception of the person as ... a distinctive whole.

So, a 'distinctive whole' is a person. Here is the rest of (1), slightly rephrased:

> [A person is] set contrastively both against other [people] and against a social and natural background

> (1) is ... a rather peculiar idea [within the context of the world's cultures].

The bit in square brackets is a pointless rephrasing of the social background that he has already mentioned.

> however incorrigible (1) may seem to us

This suggests that (1) is a concept that we believe cannot be changed.